# How to install a PHP FileInfo module on centos

Tags: php, linux, centos

How to install a PHP FileInfo module on centos

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/Fileinfo-1.0.4.tgz
tar -zxf Fileinfo-1.0.4.tgz
cd Fileinfo-1.0.4
phpize
./configure
make
```

when in doing make i m getting the following errors

```
[/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4]# make && make install
/bin/sh /var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/include -I/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/main -I/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4 -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/fileinfo.c -o fileinfo.lo 
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/include -I/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/main -I/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4 -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/fileinfo.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fileinfo.o
/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/fileinfo.c:123: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘finfo_class_functions’
/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/fileinfo.c:171: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘fileinfo_functions’
/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/fileinfo.c: In function ‘zm_startup_finfo’:
/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/fileinfo.c:187: error: ‘finfo_class_functions’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/fileinfo.c:187: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/fileinfo.c:187: error: for each function it appears in.)
/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/fileinfo.c: At top level:
/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/fileinfo.c:221: error: ‘fileinfo_functions’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/fileinfo.c: In function ‘zif_finfo_open’:
/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/fileinfo.c:269: error: ‘struct _php_core_globals’ has no member named ‘safe_mode’
/var/Fileinfo-1.0.4/fileinfo.c:269: error: ‘CHECKUID_CHECK_FILE_AND_DIR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: * [fileinfo.lo] Error 1
```

Please me out how to enable fileinfo extention

Answer (score 0):

I have simillar situation, but i use debian and php5.2.17 (i think you use < php5.3)
So, i run `./configure` with option `--with-php-config`, because by default, `./configure` use another php-config